# Cartoon: girl with blue skin can phase through walls

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have vague memories of a cartoon about space adventurers. Main characters were on a futuristic spaceship or a space station, and were wearing similar, mostly white spacesuits. I remember that one of the characters was an alien girl, who looked just like a human but with blue skin (and maybe red hair). She had the ability to phase through solid walls.
Other details that may be helpful:

- Aired on Russian TV, late 2000s to early 2010s.
- Western animation, 2D.
- Language was Russian, however, it was most likely dubbed. There were two channels that aired cartoons for children, including localized foreign cartoons: [STS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS_(TV_channel)) and Jetix, later replaced by (or renamed?) Disney Channel. Most likely, one of them aired the show.
- Despite similar character appearance and ability, it certainly wasn't an X-Men cartoon.

Comment: Did the show use 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated) animation?

Comment: It was 2d, didn't look too old either.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about when you think you watched it? Like, would it have been within the last five years? Or are we talking a decade-plus?

Comment: Possibly Ulysses 31?

Comment: I believe it was between 2005 and 2011, can't remember more precisely.

Comment: Not Ulysses 31. The girl looked older and even more human, save for distinctly blue skin.

Comment: Did it air in Russian? Was it Russian?

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim It was in Russian, almost certainly not Russian production. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is *[Buzz Lightyear of Star Command](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0260602/)*.

It was a 2D Western Animation produced by Walt Disney Television Animation and Pixar Animation Studios. The general attire of the Space Rangers is visually similar to Buzz Lightyear's mostly white space suit from the original *Toy Story*. And, while the show originally aired in the early 2000s, if "[The Dubbing Database](https://dubdb.fandom.com/wiki/Buzz_Lightyear_of_Star_Command)" can be trusted it aired at some stage on STS under the name "*Приключения Базза Лайтера из звездной команды*" ("*The Adventures of Buzz Lightyear of the Star Squad*").

[image]

The blue woman who can phase through walls must surely be **Princess Mira Nova**. Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Lightyear_of_Star_Command):

> Princess Mira Nova (voiced by Nicole Sullivan) is a rookie ranger and heir to the Tangean throne. She utilizes her people's **ability to phase through walls** (called "ghosting") and read minds.

[image]

Comment: Also the first thing that came to my mind when I saw the question

Comment: I think that screenshot of Mira Nova was part of the movie _[Buzz Lightyear of Star Command: The Adventure Begins (2000)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Lightyear_of_Star_Command%3A_The_Adventure_Begins)_, right when she discovers a bomb. The movie served to establish the foundations for the cartoon, I believe. Edit: I'm reading the movie served as the 3 first episodes of the cartoon too.